# how to set scroll on the div by setting height to percent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div i want to make it scroll top .
 when i set its height to pixel that time i am getting the scroll but when 
 i am setting it to percent i am not getting scroll

```
<div id="lblAlert" runat="server" class="warning-message" style="overflow:auto" >

// working code

scrollfun()
{
lblAlert.style.height = 65; 
}
// not working code
scrollfun()
{
lblAlert.style.height = '2%'; 
}
```

How will i do this,how can i convert pixel to percent ??
 please help

Comment: Could we have a demo on http://JSfiddle.net?

Comment: It'll allow us to see a demo of your page easily. You could instead upload it to your own server if that's more convenient to you.

Comment: if you are using jQuery go for MicroEye's solution. if not, my pure js function will work too.

Answer (score 2):

try to get height of parent element using

```
var element_Height = $(element).parent().css('height');
```

and calculate scroll height from it using

```
height = (2 / 100) * element_Height;
```

This will give you height to scroll.

Answer (score 1):

Heres my jsFiddle that does what you want http://jsfiddle.net/F8Qpx/

```
changeHeight = function (){
var obj = document.getElementById('lblAlert');
var parent = obj.parentNode;
obj.style.height = (parent.offsetHeight/100)*2 + "px";//Make 2%
}​
```

This code should work

Comment: what is this parent.offsetHeight do .is it giving me percentage not pixel ,then how can i get 72 px in percentage.(parent.offsetHeight/10) what changes i have to make in this code.actually i dont want to set height in pixel that my requirment.Will this code will not give me any cross browser issue.i am using ie.